# Android screen resolution

Tags: android, android-screen

There are some screen resolutions already defined in Android.
They are:

- QVGA (240×320, low density, small screen)
- WQVGA (240×400, low density, normal screen)
- FWQVGA (240×432, low density, normal screen)
- HVGA (320×480, medium density, normal screen)
- WVGA800 (480×800, high density, normal screen)
- WVGA854 (480×854 high density, normal screen)

How do I know which type my device screen resolution is?

Comment: What about 540x460 (Droid Bionic)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `DisplayMetrics` to get screen info from your device.

Sample code:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

final int height = dm.heightPixels;
final int width = dm.widthPixels;
```

Comment: That is the physical size of the screen.  But that does not always tell you accurately what [x]VGA resolution the device is...  Take for example HTC Thunderbolt.  It is a huge phone, yet it is classified as WVGA.  Go figure.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to search the specifications of your device? i.e. from [Wikipedia's Nexus One article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_One), you can find Nexus one screen resolution:

> Display   480 x 800 px (PenTile RGBG), 3.7 in (94 mm), 254 ppi, 3:5 aspect ratio, WVGA, 24-bit color AMOLED with 100,000:1 contrast ratio and 1 ms response rate

That's a starting point...

Comment: i want to know it from code, i need it in my application. thanks

Comment: Ok. In fact, it will be easier for you to focus on densities (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi...). You can find some useful resources here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html 
Moreover, you can also use this class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html